# First dynamic array in C

Tags: beginner, c, memory-management, vectors

I am new to C and have been learning it for about a month now.

This is my attempt to implement a dynamic array.  My code works, but i don't know whether or not it leaks memory.

But my code works as I expected.  Is my code good or bad?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct
{
    int size;
    int arr[5];
} dynamic_array;

dynamic_array *create_dynamic_array(int initial_value)
{
    dynamic_array *self = (dynamic_array *)calloc(1, sizeof(dynamic_array));
    if (self == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nCan not allocate memory\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    if (initial_value == NULL)
        return self;
    self->size = 1;
    self->arr[0] = initial_value;
    return self;
}

void print_dynamic_array(dynamic_array *self)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < self->size; i++)
    {
        printf("\nval=%d,index=%d", self->arr[i], i);
    }
    printf("\n length of arr =%d", self->size);
}

void push(dynamic_array *self, int v)
{
    int len = self->size;
    self->arr[len] = v;
    self->size = (len + 1);
}

int *get_element(dynamic_array *self, int index)
{
    if (index >= self->size)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    return &self->arr[index];
}

void remove(dynamic_array *self, int index)
{
    int *address = get_element(self, index);
    int len = self->size, i;
    for (i = 0; i < (self->size - index); i++)
    {
        *(address + i) = *(address + i + 1);
    }
    self->size = (len - 1);
    printf("\nbrooooo %p,val=%d\n", (address + i + 1), *(address + i + 1));
}
int length(dynamic_array *self)
{
    return self->size;
}


void freeDynamicArray(dynamic_array *da)
{
    //free(da->arr);
    free(da);
}


int main()

{
    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned)time(&t));
    dynamic_array *DA = create_dynamic_array(NULL);
    print_dynamic_array(DA);
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        push(DA, (rand() % 100) + 1);
    }

    print_dynamic_array(DA);
    printf("\n element at 4 is %d", *get_element(DA, 4));
    remove(DA, 7);
    print_dynamic_array(DA);
    freeDynamicArray(DA);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you avoiding to get out of the fixed boundaries of that _dynamic array_? It isn't dynamic.

Answer (score 8):

Your code does not implement a dynamic array.  It never extends its memory when elements are added, so it overflows its bounds after a number of insertions, and proceeds to overwrite memory it doesn't own - that's called a **Buffer Overflow** and can be even more serious than a mere leak.

A true dynamic array needs to use `realloc()` (and a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member)) to provision more memory when elements are added.

---

There are some things that make no sense:

> ```
> if (initial_value == NULL)
> ```

It doesn't make sense to compare an integer against a pointer - what are you trying to achieve here?

Similarly, why are we trying to pass a pointer as the initial value when we create the array, here?:

> ```
> dynamic_array *DA = create_dynamic_array(NULL);
> ```

I think it's best to get rid of the "initial value" business, and always create an empty collection.

Then we can use `malloc()` rather than `calloc()` since we assign to both members of the struct.

---

Other issues:

> ```
> dynamic_array *self = (dynamic_array *)calloc(1, sizeof(dynamic_array));
> ```

A good practice is to use `sizeof *self` rather than writing the type (it makes it easier to change the type later, and can help reviewers when the assignment is far from the declaration).  And the cast is unnecessary in C, because `void*` converts to any kind of object pointer.

So that should be:

```
dynamic_array *self = calloc(1, sizeof *self);
```

> ```
> if (self == NULL)
> {
>     printf("\nCan not allocate memory\n");
>     exit(0);
> ```

Good work considering the error case.  Error messages really ought to go to the error stream (`fprintf(stderr, …)`).  Actually, it's probably better just to return the null pointer, so the caller can decide how to report the error:

```
if (!self) {
    return self;
}
```

We certainly shouldn't be exiting with status 0, which is the *success* value.

> ```
> void remove(dynamic_array *self, int index)
> ```

We can't use that name - `remove()` is already a function in `<stdio.h>`.  I propose using a naming system where all our functions begin with `dynarr_` so we know they belong together.  So this would be `dynarr_remove()`.

> ```
> for (i = 0; i < (self->size - index); i++)
> {
>     *(address + i) = *(address + i + 1);
> }
> ```

The normal way to write the assignment is using the index operator: `address[i] = address[i+1]`.  That said, it's unnecessary: this loop can be replaced by a call to `memmove()`.

> ```
> printf("\nbrooooo %p,val=%d\n", (address + i + 1), *(address + i + 1));
> ```

We need to convert the pointer to `void*` to print it.

> ```
> dynamic_array *DA = dynarr_create();
> ```

We usually use all-caps names for preprocessor macros (because they are dangerous, and don't behave like C identifiers).  Keep local variables in lowercase.

Comment: fun fact: `struct { int size; int arr[]; }` is valid C: the array is called a "flexible array member" and you can malloc/realloc a larger size, supporting use-cases like this where you have some fixed members and a variable-sized array at the end.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member  I think this is only valid if the array size in the struct declaration is empty or `0`, though, so you couldn't just add `realloc` to the OP's existing code, you also need to change the declaration.

Comment: I should have mentioned flexible array members - I've incorporated your link.  Prior to flexible array members, it was common to have a 1-element array at the end of a struct, and I _think_ that's valid (but the size computation is harder to read).

Comment: Back in the old days before C99, compilers didn't do nearly as much optimization based on the assumption of no UB.  So back then, it would happen to work to write past the end of a 1-element array.  But if supercat is correct in comments on (*[Array of size 0 at the end of struct](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/60801981)*), a non-zero size makes it a normal array so access past the end is UB whether or not its the last member.  A compiler could assume that `p->arr[n]` actually accesses `p->arr[0]` and that `n` is `0`, because any other value would have UB.

Comment: The spec seems to be a bit ambiguous and potentially misleading in the case of a regular array with a specific size. Evaluating an array subscription `arr[n]` is UB if `arr+n` points past the end of an 'array object' that `arr` points to. The thing is that an 'object' is a 'region of data storage' and `malloc()` returns an 'object'. So 'arr' might not actually point to an 'array object' of some size, but rather to somewhere inside a bigger 'object'. 
If it's UB, things get bizarre when casting to `char *`.
Maybe this deserves it's own question on StackOverflow, if one doesn't exists already.

Comment: FYI, this question is essentially about this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43736595/can-i-over-extend-an-array-by-allocating-more-space-to-the-enclosing-struct/43736720#43736720
And *zwol*'s comment points out exactly what I mentioned above.